# Apache Tomcat error - HTTP Status 404/ whitelabel error

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, postman

I tried deploying a war file in apache tomcat and tried different services from the browser. But I'm getting the following error.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>HTTP Status 404 – Not Found</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>HTTP Status 404 – Not Found</h1>
<hr class="line" />
<p><b>Type</b> Status Report</p>
<p><b>Message</b> The requested resource [&#47;executor.war&#47;executor&#47;create] is not 
available</p>
<p><b>Description</b> The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource 
or is not
willing to disclose that one exists.</p>
<hr class="line" />
<h3>Apache Tomcat/9.0.44</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried Get and Post mapping, both are not working.
I also tried deploying and running the war file from the redirected port at 8443 but it throws the following error.

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

I also checked the URL, that's absolutely correct. e.g. http://localhost:8443/project/ping
Here project is my war file name.
My project is connected to MongoDB, will that have any effect on my project?

Please help me out solving this error. Thank you.

Comment: The `.war` part of the war file name shouldn't end up as part of your project URL.

Comment: Look in the Tomcat log-file for startup-errors of your application and post them here; look for information on your webapp using the [Tomcat Manager](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html).

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check deployed context name and use that in URL.

Tomcat server logs say's INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive[project-name-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war].

Query URL will be e.g. http://localhost:8443/project-name-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/ping